# Select time query issue in python pyodbc

Tags: python, mysql, pyodbc

I am querying a table having a time column (**dataType is time**) through python pyodbc. The column is having value `17:12:40` but through pyodbc while selecting this time column, it is returning `datetime.time(0, 0)` value.

**Example:** Query is:

```
Select arrivalTime from myTable where id =1
```

Actual value in database for `arrivalTime` is `17:12:40` but pyodbc is returning value `datetime.time(0, 0)` which is actually equivalent to null value.

Executing same query in sql interface is returning correct value. Even SqlAlchemy is also executing it correctly. Only pyodbc is returning incorrect value.

This issue is arising only when i am connecting to mySql database through pyodbc. Is there any pyodbc dependency with mySql DSN?

Is this a known issue?

Comment: *"Is this a known issue?"* - Apparently not, because I am unable to recreate it under Python 2.7.5 or Python 3.4.3 with MySQL ODBC 5.2w and the current version of pyodbc. I get `datetime.time(17, 12, 40)` as expected. If you are using an older version of pyodbc then update it to the latest version and try again. If the problem persists then [edit] your question with more details regarding the versions of the components you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're using TDS Version 7.3 throughout the stack:

- in your connection string;
- in odbc.ini;
- in FreeTDS.conf.

See here: http://www.freetds.org/userguide/choosingtdsprotocol.htm

If you're using version 8.0 in your connection string, this is incorrect; it maps for version 7.1. Only TDS Version 7.3 supports the DATE and TIME datatypes, introduced in SQL Server 2008.

Good luck!

Comment: Apparently the issue concerns MySQL, not MS SQL Server.

Comment: Gah, thanks, I always parse MySQL as MSSQL when I've already got FreeTDS on my mind. :)